# Clean image for OCR

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

I've been trying to clean this image for OCR but getting mixed results:

[image]

Best I achieved:

[image]

```
def image_smoothening(img):
    ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(th1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th2, (1, 1), 0)
    ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(
        blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return th3
    
def remove_noise_and_smooth(img):
    filtered = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img.astype(
        np.uint8), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 45, 3)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(filtered, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    img = image_smoothening(img)
    or_image = cv2.bitwise_or(img, closing)
    return or_image
```

Any clue as to what I'm missing?

Comment: You could binarize the image with a very low threshold. Then perform region labelling on the black areas. Remove the largest labelled region. The remaining mask should be all the characters.

Comment: @Karson
Thanks, I tried things and got to the same conclusion. How would I go about labeling the black areas? Finding contours is no trouble, but how do you check for their color?

Comment: you could implement your own region growing algorithm or you could use a library. A quick search for Python examples shows https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label which I believe would do the trick. You need to ensure that you binarize the image before trying to label.

Answer (score 4):

My MATLAB code to solve it. I know you are writing in Python so you'll have to translate.

```
%Read in
im = imread('DuQy7.png');
%Convert to grayscale
img = rgb2gray(im);
img = rescale(img);
%Binarize with threshold of 0.7/1.0
imbw = imbinarize(img,0.7/1);
%Flip blacks/whites
imbw = imcomplement(imbw);
%Label, L is labelled image, n is # of labels
[L,n] = bwlabeln(imbw);

count = zeros(n,1);
[y,x] = size(L);

%Get count for each label
L = uint8(L);
for j=1:y
    for i=1:x
        if L(j,i) ~= 0
            count(L(j,i)) = count(L(j,i)) + 1;
        end
    end
end

%Find label with most values in image
max = 0;
maxi = 1;
for index=1:n
    if max < count(index)
        max = count(index);
        maxi = index;
    end
end

%Replace large region and color other labels to white
for j=1:y
    for i=1:x
        if L(j,i) == maxi
            L(j,i) = 0;
        elseif L(j,i) ~= 0
            L(j,i) = 256;
        end
    end
end

%view and save
imshow(L)
imwrite(L,'outputTXT.bmp');
```

[image: output-TXT.png]

You could probably better adjust the threshold to better cut out background regions that got included. You could also look for labelled regions that are very small and remove them since they are probably erroneously included.

Some parts of the background are going to be impossible to get rid of since they are indistinguishable from the actual symbols. For example, between symbol x2,y1 and x2,y2 there is a black background region between the outlined white which is the same value as the symbols. Therefore it would be very difficult to parse out.

Comment: The labeling step, what exactly does it remove?

Comment: @L14n the labelling step is set up to remove the background gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do "division normalization" in Python/OpenCV to remove the background. But that will not help with the outline font issue.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('img.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (3,3))
smooth = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# alternate blur in place of morphology
#smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15,15), 0)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

# threshold
result = cv2.threshold(division, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# save results
cv2.imwrite('img_thresh.png',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.imshow('result', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]